# Material Angular add regular expressions (regex) to filter

Tags: regex, angular, filter, angular-material

I want to use regular expression on material table data filter. So far I've achieved using a filter for each column on my table, but no idea on how to approach the regex functionality. I've read about changing the `customfilterpredicate`, but can't seem to do it.

My filtering code is very long, but here's how my `customfilterpredicate` looks like. I want to transform it using regex expressions:

```js
customFilterPredicate() {
    const myFilterPredicate = (data: IApiDataFile, filter: string): boolean => {
      const searchString = JSON.parse(filter);
      const unitFound = data.unit.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.unit.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      const file_nameFound = data.file_name.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.file_name.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

      if (searchString.topFilter) {
        return unitFound || file_nameFound;
      } else {
        return unitFound && file_nameFound;
      }
    };
    return myFilterPredicate;
  }
  
 filterSubscribe() {
    this.unitFilter.valueChanges.subscribe(unitFilterValue => {
      this.filteredValues.unit = unitFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
      this.filteredValues.topFilter = false;
      console.log('in filterSubscribe()');

    });

    this.file_nameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe(file_nameFilterValue => {
      this.filteredValues.file_name = file_nameFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
      this.filteredValues.topFilter = false;
    });
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate();
  }
```

then

```html
 public ngOnInit() {
    interval(60 * 1000).pipe(
        flatMap(() => this.ApiDataFileService.getApiDataFiles())).subscribe(
        ApiDataFiles => {
            this.filteredApiDataFiles = ApiDataFiles;
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IApiDataFile>(this.filteredApiDataFiles);
            this.filterSubscribe();
            this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
            this.filteredValues.topFilter = false;
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = error as any
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the property filterPredicate of the data source. If your dataSource is the typical of the examples

```
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
```

You can define a regExpr variable that change in applyFilterFunction

```
  regExpr:any;  //<--define a variable

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.regExpr = new RegExp(filterValue);
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

then you can make a function like

```
regExprFilter()
  { 
    return (data: any, filter: string) => {
        try {
          return this.regExpr.test(data.name)
        } catch (e) {
          return false
        }
      }
  }
```

And in ngOnInit change the filterPredicate

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate =this.regExprFilter()
}
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7imht8-9m8mpq?file=app/table-filtering-example.ts)

NOTE:I edited my answer to make more confortable code

NOTE2: Be carefull using regExp if you want defined using a string variable in code. you need take acount "\" must be write as "\\", e.g.

```
  let myExpresion="^\w" //BAD, myExpresion get the value "^w"
  let myExpresion="^\\w" //GOOD, myExpresion get the value "^\w"
```